# Selenium Web driver on Xen Desktop

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xen

I use Selenium Web Driver with java as the language using Eclipse IDE. 
I have recently been provided a Xen Desktop. So all software's - Eclipse IDE, Firefox browsers & JDK/JRE are installed on a shared drive & we access them remotely when we login into the XEN desktops.

So when I try to launch the Firefox application through Selenium WD, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: VISTA
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
      at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.<init>(Executable.java:72)
      at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:59)
      at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:55)
      at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
      at CodeBase.FirstProgram.main(FirstProgram.java:28)
```

So I gather that Selenium WD cannot find the Firefox install path. 
But I am able to launch the Firefox browser manually.

My assumption here is, since it is a virtual environment, everytime I login into the environment, the Firefox path changes. My question is, can we use selenium Webdriver on a Xen Desktop where all the install path's are shared drives? Or is my assumption wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In case of executing your cases remotely, you should consider making use of [Selenium Grid 2](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2). Here you will have a Grid server and your browser instance will be over node. RemoteWebDriver would be used in order to run your test over the node located remotely.

Else, if your firefox is installed on not the default location you can consider following code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(new File("path/to/your/firefox.exe")), firefoxDesiredProfile);
```

Also, make sure the firefox version you use is compatible with WebDriver

Comment: FF Version is 28.0; WebDriver version is 2.39. I tried adding the FF path during initialization, but that gave a similar PATH not found error.  I am planning to shift to a VDI which has a fixed install path to solve this issue. So far, no luck with the same environment. Even with Selenium Grid, I will need to know the exact path of the FF install right?